# Regular Expression don't match one word

Tags: regex

I have the following regexp `([a-z]+)\s([a-z]+)\s([a-z]+)` and the following input
`block right here str` 
It matches 3 words(block right here), but I want it to match at most 3 words until it sees `str`, so the following input `block right str` should match only `block right`, but `block right left str` should match `block right left`.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want to match *at most* 3 words, or either 2 or 3 words (not counting 'str'). It's also not clear whether the 'str' suffix is optional or required. In other words, are `block str` and `block right` valid input strings?

Answer (score 4):

```
^(?!.*\bstr\b)([a-z]+)\s([a-z]+)\s([a-z]+)$
```

A `negative lookahead` should do it for you.

EDIT:

for the edited question you will need to use

```
(\b(?:(?!\bstr\b)[a-z])+)\s(\b(?:(?!\bstr\b)[a-z])+)\s(\b(?:(?!\bstr\b)[a-z])+)?
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/128

Comment: Was about to submit my answer.. you were faster.

Answer (score 2):

This regex should do the job:

```
^(?:([a-z]+)\s)?(?:([a-z]+)\s)(?:([a-z]+)\s)?str$
```

It matches three optional words followed by a space (`(?:([a-z]+)\s)?`) and then matches a trailing `str`.

It [correctly matches](https://regex101.com/r/oD3pP2/1):

- block str
- block right str
- block right left str

But not:

- block right left extra
- str
- block
- block right
- block right left